# Finding two elements whose difference is greater than or equal to D

Tags: algorithm, sorting, range

Lets say you have an array

2 6 4 2 9 4 2

You want to  find two elements whose difference is greater than 6. In this case one possible answer is (9,2). How would you do this in less that O(N^2) time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

idea .1

1) you sort your numbers O(n lgn)

2) if difference between last and first element is your number (6). you found them (first and last elements). If the difference is smaller, there are no such elements

idea .2

Min and max elements. If difference between them is less then your seek number, there is no such pair of elements.  Time: O(n)

Answer (score 2):

Just scan for the minimum and maximum values.  O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Just loop on the elements while storing two numbers, the minimum and maximum obtained so far.

- If at any point, you find such a pair that satisfies the condition, thats your answer.
- If you reach the end of the array, no such pair exists.

Worst case time: O(n)